# Adoption Mixups & Matrilineal Descent

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism

A most perplexing question was posed to me today, curious to see others thoughts --

A baby girl is adopted after the first day of birth. The adoptive parents are a frum couple who are told the baby's mother is Jewish by reputable sources. They are full believers in the truth of this information.

They raise their daughter, Beis Yaakov, seminary in Yerushalayim, marries a Cohen, and b"h, eventually two baby boys. Both undergo bris according to Halakah.

The woman's boys too grow up, go to yeshiva, receive simcha, chuppa, kollel, and have children of their own.

As the years pass their mother begins looking for her birth parents, only to find out to her astonishment, after years and years of searching, that her birth mother was indeed, not Jewish.

What is her halakhic standing? That of her sons? What is their standing? That of their Kohan status? Their smichas? Their own children? Must a conversion to be done to all three generations? Must a bris be redone? Do any other problems arise in your minds? Remedies?

Keep in mind that we are discussing frum families (shomrei mitzvos) according to Halakha, answered pertaining to Reform or Conservative laws are not relevant to the question.

Comment: Close as duplicate of http://yodeya.com/q/52891/?

Comment: By the way, re "marries a Cohen": no rabbi should have presided over that wedding. (Not saying that none *would*. Just that none *should*. That was the breakdown in the sequence of events, I think.)

Comment: @msh210 I do not think that it is a duplicate as the other question involves someone whose is Jewish attempting to leave  and the effect on their descendants. This is a situation in which someone who **thought** they were Jewish was not. I have read of a case in which a Yeshivah boy found out that a maternal ancestor had undergone an invalid conversion and he had to be megayer. I also know of a case in which a woman had to undergo a kosher giyur when she went to be married in Eretz Yisrael because of a similar situation.

Comment: @sabbahillel that was just one example in the question.  The basic question there is broader, and seems to include much (if not all) of this one.

Comment: @YeZ it's not the same question at all.

Comment: @FlushingHasid Yes it is. You ask: Are these people jewish? That question asks: Is this person jewish? Same quesiton

Comment: It's obvious that they aren't Jewish. This isn't the question. The question regards the remedy to the issue. But you're right, nitpicking is really the whole reason I asked. Thanks for your extremely useful insight :)

Comment: @FlushingHasid You asked a legitimate question and I directed you to a legitimate answer. I do not blame you in the slightest for having asked an on-topic question. Asking a duplicate question is not embarrassing.

Comment: @DoubleAA It's not even close to what you claim as duplicate - it's a question on its own!

Comment: THere are cases when **a Bais Din could rule to discard the evidence out and leave the situation as de-facto Jewish**. I heard that explicitly from my knowledgeable Chevrusah. We do search for the truth, but a BD has the right to override the truth.

Answer (score 0):

If the grandmother is considered a convert than she shouldn't have married a kohen and her sons are chalalim. If she wasn't a convert than her sons are not Jewish. In either case the sons children are Jewish (as their mothers are Jewish) but the daughters should not marry kohanim (either because they are chalalot or because their father is not Jewish). Their is still an open question of whether the grandsons will be chalalim and whether their daughters can marry kohanim.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, ykay. Please [edit] your post to include how you know this to be true (sources), as we have no idea who you are and can't just take your word for it. Hope to see you around.

Comment: Why would the grandmother be considered a convert?

Comment: The grandmother was never considered to be a convert. She was thought to be Jewish.

Comment: I think it would be preferable for the grandmother not to be considered a convert as then her children are not chalalim. The fact that she went to the mikvah and always thought she was Jewish could possible qualify her as a convert but I don't have a source for this.